# Does Flask use Jinja2 bytecode cache by default?

Tags: flask, jinja2

Jinja2 offers [bytecode cache](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#bytecode-cache). Is it used by default in Flask? If not, how can it be enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Flask does not use a bytecode cache. The default configuration for the Jinja environment is found in [`Flask.jinja_options`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.jinja_options), and Flask can add `autoescape` and `auto_reload` based of Flask configuration, see the [`Flask.create_jinja_environment()` documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.create_jinja_environment).

You can set the `bytecode_cache` attribute on the Jinja enviroment that Flask manages afte the fact, on the [`Flask.jinja_env` reference](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.jinja_env). E.g., to configure a [filesystem bytecode cache](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.FileSystemBytecodeCache) with the default TMPDIR-based location, you can use:

```
app.jinja_env.bytecode_cache = jinja2.FileSystemBytecodeCache()
```